# How can I open the same page in Chrome without opening a new page webbrowser python

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

i do not need to open new page in chrome, I have to use the same existing page

I am trying to send WhatsApp messages using Python from the web, but every time it opens a new page and downloads WhatsApp Web again.
I need help

def sendwhatmsg_instantly(phone_no: str, message: str, wait_time: int = 20) -> None:
"""Send WhatsApp Message Instantly"""
parsed_message = quote(message)

```
web.open(f"https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={phone_no}&text={quote(message)}")
time.sleep(wait_time)
pg.press('enter')
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you using [pywhatkit](https://pypi.org/project/pywhatkit/)? I agree with @D.L, please make your question clearer.

Comment: Python has no idea what "the existing page" is though: you could  have 100 tabs open, how would it know which one to replace? If you mean "make the page I am working with navigate to a new URL" then inject an `<a href="...">` into the page and have the code make the page "click" that.

Comment: I am using webbrowser function

web.open(f"https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={phone_no}&text={quote(message)}")

Comment: Is there other solutions rather than webbrowser